# How do I get the virtual keyboard in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, virtual-keyboard

I've read that this is not possible but that was from a discussion from about 4 months ago. Some Windows Phone 7 games do display the keyboard so surely it must be doable now?

edit: just to clarify I want to show it in an XNA application.

Comment: Just to be clear, you mean within an XNA application? It may be worth making that explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Guide.BeginShowKeyboardInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975190.aspx) method.

In addition to the MSDN docs there is an blog post showing usage at http://luisguerrero.net/en/2010/07/17/how-to-access-to-keyboard-in-xna-from-windows-phone-7/